# how to unit test promise that modifies a variable that gets sent to a 3rd party in typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am writing my first set of unit tests for typescript code and having hard time figuring our how to test `processRecord` method since it doesn't return the array that contains key logic output.

```
 export const processRecord = async (event, context: AppContext) => {
  if (!event.Records) {
    return false;
  }

  const promises = event.Records.map(async (record: DynamoDBRecord) => {
    try {
      if (!record.dynamodb) {
        return false;
      }

      let newInsuranceNamesList: string[] = [];
      
      ...
      // some logic to update newInsuranceNamesList
      ...

      await sendTo3rdParty(newInsuranceNamesList);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Checking when `event.Records` or `record.dynamodb` doesn't exist is easy because it returns `false`.
But the only real way for me to test `processRecord` is by checking contents of `newInsuranceNamesList` array. How can I achieve it in unit test?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, simple answer - refactor and pull the logic that determines `newInsuranceNamesList` into its own method and unit test it